# Not able to replace the value of the variable inside expression in bash script

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to run a bash script, where I would like to  make POST calls in a for loop as follows:

```
for depId in "${depIds[@]}"
do
  echo "$depId"  <--------------------------------- THIS IS PRINTING PROPER VALUE
  curl 'https://student.service.com/api/student' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: UISESSION=abcd' \
  --data-raw '{"name":"Student Name","description":"Dummy","depId":$depId}' \  <---- HERE I CANNOT GET THE VALUE OF THE VARIABLE
  --compressed
  echo "$content"
done
```

As mentioned above, I cannot get the value of the department id in the URL, with the above form, I am getting a Request Malformed exception. I have even tried with `${depId}`, but no luck.

Could anyone please help here ?

Comment: The string is not interpolated because it begins and ends with `'`.

Comment: `$depId` is inside single quotes hence not getting expanded. Use `--data-raw '{"name":"Student Name","description":"Dummy","depId":"'"$depId"'"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping your quotes around the variable.

```
  --data-raw '{"name":"Student Name","description":"Dummy","depId":'"$depId"'}' \
```